# R - Identical values in columns of dataframe in one row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, overlap

I have a data frame containing 3 columns of non-integer values. The values in the respective columns allot of the time will be identical to values in the other one or two columns in the same data frame. If there are matches between columns I would like to have them on the same row.

See **subset_df** vs **expected_subset_df** below for clarification.

> Notice that the values ending on *"248:-"* are in the same row in **expected_subset_df** but not in **subset_df**.
>   
>   Summary: values in col1 can also be in col2 and/or col3. If the values between columns do match I want them on the same row.

```
> subset_df
         col1          col2          col3
1 20:31722330:- 20:31722330:- 20:31722330:-
2 20:31722348:- 20:31724051:- 20:31724051:-
3         FALSE 20:31722348:- 20:31722348:-
```

```
> expected_subset_df
         col1          col2          col3
1 20:31722330:- 20:31722330:- 20:31722330:-
2 20:31722348:- 20:31722348:- 20:31722348:-
3         FALSE 20:31724051:- 20:31724051:-
```

## What I have attempted

```
library(dplyr)
subset_df %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
        mutate(col1 = subset_df$col1[match(subset_df$col2, subset_df$col1)],
        col3 = subset_df$col3[match(subset_df$col2, subset_df$col3)])
```

Yields:

```
         col1          col2          col3
1 20:31722330:- 20:31722330:- 20:31722330:-
2          <NA> 20:31724051:- 20:31724051:-
3 20:31722348:- 20:31722348:- 20:31722348:-
```

> Is this method robust? Is there a better alternative?

### Edit:

Suppose dataframe **breakpoint** looks like this:

```
> breakpoint
         col1           col2            col3
1 20:31722330:- 20:31722344:-            FALSE
2 21:15014555:- 21:15014555:-            FALSE
3 21:15014767:- 21:15014767:-    21:15014767:-
```

How can I turn dataframe **breakpoint** into this:

```
> expected_breakpoint
         col1           col2          col3
1 20:31722330:-          <NA>          <NA>
2          <NA>  20:31722344:-         <NA>
3 21:15014555:-  21:15014555:-         <NA>
4          <NA>          <NA>         FALSE
5          <NA>          <NA>         FALSE
6 21:15014767:-  21:15014767:-  21:15014767:-
```

### Edit 2: `FALSE` into `<NA>` before analysis

Suppose dataframe **breakpoint_new** looks like this:

```
> breakpoint_new
         col1           col2            col3
1 20:31722330:- 20:31722344:-            <NA>
2 21:15014555:- 21:15014555:-            <NA>
3 21:15014767:- 21:15014767:-    21:15014767:-
```

How can I turn dataframe **breakpoint_new** into this:

```
> expected_breakpoint_new
         col1           col2          col3
1 20:31722330:-          <NA>          <NA>
2          <NA>  20:31722344:-         <NA>
3 21:15014555:-  21:15014555:-         <NA>
4 21:15014767:-  21:15014767:-  21:15014767:-
```

Comment: In your `expected_breakpoint`, how do you camee up with `21:15014344:-` in 'col2' for 2nd row.  It is not in showed in thee input 'breakpoint' data

Comment: @akrun Typos, fixed it

Comment: is there a precedence for col1 > col2 > col3 in terms of the number of rows it will move downward when there is no match.  In your previous  expected_subset_df, the `FALSE` didn't create a new row

Comment: @akrun All columns are of equal importance. I am trying to illustrate with `expected_breakpoint` that for some value in some column, this value is trying to be matched with values in other columns. If it finds a matching value in the other columns, they are put on the same row and otherwise a `<NA>` is introduced indicating no match with any value (on any row) in the other dataframes was found. That `FALSE` didn't create a new row in `expected_subset_df` is a valid point. It indeed doesn't have to make a new row. The only requiredment is that the `FALSE` stays.

Comment: The `FALSE` values can be omitted after they create a new row for themselves. They are not used to create a [venn diagram](https://imgur.com/a/9geqy8K). The venn diagram uses `expected_breakpoint`. The `FALSE` in a column only indicates that the column doesn't have this item and thus it doesn't show up in the venn diagram. Later I will convert `expected_breakpoint` into a binary matrix (string is TRUE, while FALSE or <NA> is FALSE).

Comment: I suppose the `FALSE`'s in `expected_breakpoint` can be turned to `<NA>` before trying to find matches. I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function solves my problem:

```
match_columns = function(df, nomatch=F){
  if (ncol(df) != 3){
    stop("Input DataFrame needs to have 3 columns")
  }
  matrix = matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0)
  match12 = intersect(df$object, df$object.1)
  match23 = intersect(df$object.1, df$object.2)
  match13 = intersect(df$object, df$object.2)


  for (item in match12){
    if (item == nomatch){next}
    if (item %in% match23){
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(rep(item, 3)))
    }else{
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(rep(item, 2), nomatch))
    }
  }

  for (item in match13){
    if (item == nomatch){next}
    if (!(item %in% match12)){
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(item, nomatch, item))
    }
  }

  for (item in match23){
    if (item == nomatch){next}
    if (!(item %in% match13)){
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(nomatch, rep(item, 2)))
    }
  }

  for (item in df$object){
    if (item == nomatch){next}
    if (!(item %in% match12) & !(item %in% match13)){
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(item, rep(nomatch, 2)))
    }
  }

  for (item in df$object.1){
    if (item == nomatch){next}
    if (!(item %in% match12) & !(item %in% match23)){
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(nomatch, item, nomatch))
    }
  }

  for (item in df$object.2){
    if (item == nomatch){next}
    if (!(item %in% match13) & !(item %in% match23)){
      matrix = rbind(matrix, c(rep(nomatch, 2), item))
    }
  }

  return(matrix)
}
```

Values in their respective columns are matched with identical values in other columns. `FALSE`'s are introduced if not all three columns match.